# Show icon/image from Directus dropdown in table

Tags: directus

I have a table in MySQL that we want to use/show as a dashboard in Directus. We want to display a red or green icon to show the status for multiple columns on multiple rows.

We have created a dropdown in the Directus datamodel with text "red" or "green" and as value the URL to the corresponding files in the Directus File Library formatted as <img src=> HTML.

Permissions have been set properly (we can show/open the images via URL using the assets id) but we cannot get the images to display properly when looking at the table in Directus. It looks like something is displayed but not the actual images (see below):
[image: Directus situation]

If we look at the same table using SuperSet everything works as expected and looks like this:

[image: SuperSet situation]

Is it possible to show the images within Directus or is it simply not possible?